Black screen problem before openings app in flutter
Black screen is coming screen before app opening or before splash screen. how to solve it? if the device also be faster it is showing and if the device is slower the problem is showing for lot of time. The following picture show the app icon
enter image description here
When I am clicking the app, the app is showing a black screen for 6 or 8 seconds. The following picture is showing the problem.
enter image description here
After this the onboarding or splahscreen is showing as you can seen in the following picture.
enter image description here
I have searched many time but nothing found.

Hack the Flutter
You probably waiting for an async code in your main() function. That's why black screen appears before a runApp kicks in. Show just some loading indicator widget for the time of the async code running.
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Showing loading widget while awaiting your async code
  runApp(
    const Center(
      child: PlatformActivityIndicator(), // your activity indicator widget
    ),
  );

  // awaiting code here

  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}


What is PlatformActivityIndicator() if it means what I want to show in before main app is running like splash screen or onboarding, also not worked.
